# How can I make Linux as secure as possible?

Tags: security, distribution-choice

With the rise of Windows 10 I am getting more concerned about my privacy and the risks of using an unsecured system. My question is three fold

- Which distro of Linux is most secure?
- How do keep the operating system secure as I use it?
- What technologies does Linux use to keep me secure (e.g. SELinux)?

Comment: What distributions is the most secure is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Yes but there must be set (maybe 5-8) that are considered to be security oriented. Or there are security features that some distros have and so do not.

Comment: Any linux distribution might be set to the equal level of security. As you are speaking on a workstation, then SELinux is not really an advantage if you keep the usual vectors of possible attack under control.

Comment: I recommend taking more specific questions around this theme to http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The good thing of Linux is that every Linux can be tuned up to be equal secure than other one. So, select your favorite distro to start over and begin to secure it in the way you prefer.

If you want to hardening your Linux distro, check out these topics:

- Users / groups privileges (don't do everything as root)
- IPTables (Linux firewall)
- SELinux
- Encrypt your filesystems
- Proxychains

Also you can check your system with Lynis. Look for info, it's very useful.

Ubuntu, CentOS, Debian... are secure in the same way.